# Get Facebook comments via Graph API, but not hidden comments from the social plugin Facebook comments box

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I already use the [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API)  to get Facebook comments from a URL. That's working nice.

But I have a problem. Comments that are hidden from the box (social plugin), and are displayed in the JSON response of the API. But I don't want those to appear in. And there is no field to get information if it's a moderated comment or not.

```
Array(
    [id] => 10150178257599373_16650724
    [from] => Array
    (
        [name] => Books, EBooks
        [category] => Author
        [id] => 182404265135935
    )
    [message] => Thank you, Facebook
    [created_time] => 2011-06-06T03:21:06+0000
)
```

As you can see, there is no field with the information "moderate". What do I do?

Comment: Similar to question: 

[Is there a way to filter out moderated comments with the graph API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475075/is-there-a-way-to-filter-out-moderated-comments-with-the-graph-api) See answers there also :-)

Answer (score 1):

Double moderate!

You could create a database entry for every new comment via the [Fb.Event.subscribe](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) and as soon as you moderated the comment on Facebook, mark the comment in your database and only print out the marked comments. It's a bit annoying, but so far propably the only solution :(

It would be great if Facebook could implement that information in their JSON, or better only put moderated comments in the Graph API.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this recently and was able to use FQL to get the comments without those which are marked private (which I assume means unmoderated?)  I did this in javascript, but there is no reason this code couldn't be rewritten in php or whatever.

```
 fql = "SELECT post_fbid, fromid, object_id, text, time, comments FROM comment WHERE object_id IN (SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url ='" + commentsUrl + "') and is_private = 0 limit 10";
```

After getting back this data, loop through and grab all the user ids:

```
FB.api({method: 'fql.query',query: fql},function (comments) {
    $.each(comments, function (index, comment) {
       userIds.push(comment.fromid);
    });
});
```

With the user ids, use the graph api to get each users name and create an object that resembles the json response of the graph api:

```
FB.api('?ids=' + userIds.join(','), function (responseIds) { 

    $.each(comments, function (index, comment) {
        comment.message = comment.text;
        comment.created_time = comment.time;
        comment.from = {id: comment.fromid, name: responseIds[comment.fromid].name};

    });
});
```