# Is there a way to filter out moderated comments with the graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, comments

We use comment moderation, and the graph API is returning everything (including comments that should be hidden).  There doesn't appear to be a way to see the status of the comments or filter them out of the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FQL to query only comments that are public. Use the is_private column of comment table to do it (as Ryan says). Let me add some examples:

For example to see [only public comments](https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select%20post_fbid,%20fromid,%20object_id,%20text,%20time%20from%20comment%20where%20object_id%20in%20%28select%20comments_fbid%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url%20=%27http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/%27%29%20and%20is_private%20=%200&pretty=1):

```
SELECT post_fbid, fromid, object_id, text, time \
FROM comment \
WHERE object_id IN \
  (SELECT comments_fbid \
   FROM link_stat \
   WHERE url ='http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/') \
  AND is_private = 0
```

Note that you can also make multiple queries to get more info about the user, for example:

```
# select comments from url
query1 = "SELECT post_fbid,fromid, object_id, text, time, comments "\
        "FROM comment WHERE object_id IN " \
        "(SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url ='%s')" \
        " and is_private = 0" % (url)

# select all users from query1 and get their names and ids
query2 = "SELECT uid, name FROM user " \
         "WHERE uid IN (SELECT fromid FROM #query1)"

# let use string and not json.dumps cos ordering is important
query = '{"query1": "%s", "query2": "%s"}' % (query1, query2)

# make query to facebook using fql  and the query...
final_query = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=%s" % query
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to filter out moderated comments by querying the [comment](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/) table with [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/).  The comment table has an is_private field that you can use to filter out the moderated comments.